# Setup listbox selectedItem event in Expression Blend

Tags: silverlight-4.0, listbox, expression-blend

I am trying to learn to use Expression Blend to build SilverLight UI. I am currently working with the ListBox and have managed to add it to my page. In addition, the list box is data-bound to a sample data source defined in Blend.

But I am unable to figure out how to wire up the selectedItem event in Blend. Is this not possible in Blend and do I need to do this part in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the ListBox, go to the Properties Pane.  Next to the Name of the control there are two buttons - Properties and Events.  If you click on the Events button it will switch to showing you all of the Events, of which the SelectionChanged event is listed.  Note that there is not a "SelectedItem" event, only the SelectionChanged event.  The SelectedItem property represents the currently selected item of the ListBox.

Hope that helps.